# How can we share sdk/Framework which is having library, to some other project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, sdk, frameworks

I want to share framework in another app. I am facing issues when I have some libraries/pods like Alamofire in my framework. what is the solution of this problem? how can i use that library in framework? Also i tried to install Alamofire pod in to the other app in which i have added framework, and tried to access in my framework class but this was not accessible. please guide me how to do it. Thank you

Comment: A framework should be stand alone really. But if you really want to use another library in your framework, then you should just copy the source and add it to your code manually. A framework that relies on other libraries to work is simply bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cocoapods to achieve that. Basically, cocoapods will create a framework for you from the source files that you define and will also install the appropriate dependencies that you define in the target project when the target project does `pod install`.

Apart from cocoapods, you can also use Carthage which is also a dependency management tool.

You can read more about cocoapods [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/) and how to create a new pod [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks @Kerry, it worked and the only solution was creating pod.

Comment: Could you accept the answer and close the question?

Comment: can you guide me how to close question? i am new on stack overflow. Thank you